# Definition de $L^1((0,T);W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R))$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, measurable-functions, bochner-spaces

I have some trouble about the definition of the space $L^1((0,T);W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$, on one side the formal definition given by Bochner consists in the set of measurable functions $u$ from $(0,T)$ to $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$ (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) such that

\begin{equation}
\int_0^T \|u(t)\|_{W^{1,\infty}}<+\infty. \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

Measurability is equivalent ([Pettis' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_measurable_function)) to weak measurability and almost surely (almost everywhere?)  separably valued. Namely $t\mapsto G u(t)$ is measurable from $(0,T)$ to $\mathbb R$ for all $G\in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)'$ (topological dual space)  and there exists a negligeable subset $N$ of $(0,T)$ such that $\{f(t)\, |\, t\in(0,T)\setminus N\}$ is a separable subset of $W^{1,\infty}$.

On the other side I read sometimes it is the space of functions $u$ from $(0,T)$ to $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$ such that $u(t) \in W^{1,\infty}$ for almost all $t\in(0,T)$ and $(1)$ holds.

But I have some doubt on the consistency of the second definition. Considering such a function, I would verify the first definition is fullfilled, but the dual space of $W^{1,\infty}$ is somewhat misterious to me and moreover $W^{1,\infty}$ is not separable so proving almost surely separated valued seems tricky.

Is the second definition is false or at least a sufficient criterion of integrability?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second definition is bogus. In fact, if you only assure that $u(t) \in W^{1,\infty}$ for (almost) all $t \in (0,T)$, the function
$$ t \mapsto \|u(t)\|_{W^{1,\infty}}$$
might fail to be measurable, hence the left-hand side of (1) is not even well defined.

Moreover, the separability condition is crucial. There are weakly measurable $u$, for which (1) holds, but which fail to be almost surely separably valued. I think that
$$ u(t) := \max(t, \cdot) \in W^{1,\infty}$$
defines such a function.

Comment: So  measurability in  $L^1(0,T;W{1,\infty})$ or simply in  $L^1(0,T;L^\infty)$  is not trivial. There is no simple criterion for measurability? What I see is showing that  $\{u(t) | t\in (0,T)\}$ is for instance compact and for the weak measurability it is more complicated. The only trivial way I imagine is proving that $u$ is a simple limit of $u^n$ in $C(0,T;L^\infty)$ in the sense $\|u^n(t)-u(t)\|_\infty \to 0$ for all, or a.e., $t$ right?

Comment: You can also use Pettis' theorem (it is a characterization). However, it is not immediate that $\{u(t)\}$ is separable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was just looking for more practical characterization. Thanks a lot.